# Django: Sanitize form data?

Tags: django, forms, sanitization

I have a django project and the forms are constructed in HTML rather than as a django object.  I retrieve the values via a post class function in the view.  Because I'm not constructing forms through django, do I need to sanitize the form data?  If I need to sanitize the data, what django method can I use?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So why reinvent the wheel when django offers you the ability to use a form and do all the dirty work? What's so special that does not allow you to use a the build in implementation?

Comment: It has to do with the current backend.  Otherwise, I'd definitely go with the built-in security!

Comment: Are we talking about the django admin? or the frontend? either way you can create a form, bypass the html generated one, if you still need to style the output of the form, either override the template or use a django package such as django crispy forms. Creating a form would not require that much effort, even if this is a complex form, validation would take up way more time coding from scratch rather than using a django form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason why you can't construct a Form class that respects the parameters of the HTML form.  There's not really any magic to it.  Django offers tools to generate the HTML pragmatically, but you don't *have to* use it.

You can leverage all the power of Django's form validation--just make sure the Form class fields align with the field names in your HTML and bind it to the POST data.  If your Form's parameters change, you'll have to update the markup.

Comment: That's what I started doing.  I just wanted to make sure I wasn't neglecting any security measures.  Thanks!

Comment: Yup, you should still be in good shape.  You'll still have CSRF protection if that's turned on and any data you send to the DB will be sanitized at the ORM level.